# jQuery.ajax Определить последний success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Прохожу по массиву с файлами, загружаю на сервер. Загрузка происходит в асинхронном режиме, поэтому обработчики `success` отрабатывают уже после завершения цикла `for`.
Нужно каким-то образом определить обработчик success последнего загруженного файла.

```
//отправка файлов прошедших проверку
self.sendFiles = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.forUpload.length; i += 1) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', self.forUpload[i]);
        $.ajax(someUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (file) {
                self.files.push(file);
                //если это последний запрос ajax,
                //делаем что-то
            }
        });
    }
    //очищаем массив файлов для загрузки
    self.forUpload = [];
};
```

К счетчику `i` не привязаться, в сам метод `success` ничего "своего" не передать.
Как решить задачу?

Comment: удаляйте из массива соответствующий file элемент. массив пустой - последний ajax

Comment: @splash58 нуу, либо сделать массив промайзов, и когда они все будут исполнены, корень вызовет метод `.success()`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев это мне кажется и на ответ претендует, по крайней мере интересно

Comment: @splash58, цикл отработает раньше чем методы success (массив всегда будет пуст)

Comment: @pavelchervov не в цикле предлагается это делать, а в success функции

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, могли примерчик навоять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уже когда то отвечали на подобные вопросы, зачастую на en.SO.

Для начала тебе нужно собрать массив твоих запросов!

Например так:

```
var events = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    events.push($.ajax({...})); // вот в принципе твой $.ajax
}

$.when.apply($, events).then(function(result) {
   // Когда промисы все будут выполнены
});
```

Так как ты сразу после инициализации событий будешь подписываться, твои промисы не успеют выполнится, и `callback` сработает.

Живой пример: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YNGcm/21/)

1. [Ссылка на источник en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050866/)
2. [jQuery документация](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/#jQuery-when-deferreds)

Comment: Красиво! когда-то читал, но не разу не пользовался... +1

Comment: Спасибо, разбираюсь...

Comment: чем отличается `$.when.apply(null, events)` на jsfiddle от вашего `$.when.apply($, events)` ?

Comment: @Jean-Claude ну по правилам, в `apply` первым параметром нужно передавать контекст, но в этом случае что `null`, что `$` никакой роли не играет, контекст всегда возвращается из метода определенной структуры.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, а зачем вообще передать через apply, можно же и так сделать $.when(events).done(function(){//do something}) ?

Comment: @pavelchervov нет нельзя, тогда список параметров ты не получишь )) У тебя сначала выполнится твой `$.when.done`, а уже потом твои промайзы прилетят. Сравни то как ты сказал выводя в консоль `arguments` в обоих случаях. Увидишь разницу.

Comment: @pavelchervov если передавать один аякс, то да, но у вас же их много. В доках есть примеры, либо через запятую, либо через apply()

Comment: @Jean-Claude верно

Comment: Да, точно, тонкий момент!

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант это "промисофицировать" ваши аяксы и использовать 
[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
   var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'Первое');
   });
   var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Второе')
   });
   Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(data) {
     console.log('Все промисы выполнились!')
     console.log(data)
   })
```

Comment: Спасибо! Нативный промайс мощная штука, но пока решил сделать по старинке.